# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instapy' and 'selenium'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, module, instapy

I am experiencing this error message with every lines of code I use and with every modules also if they are correctly installed

I got error about "No module named 'selenium'" and "No module named 'instapy'"
but on cmd if I try to install them again everything is already satisfied

one weird thing: on cmd python modules I got this warning:

```
D:\Users\Sara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
```

I'm glad if you could help me
Please, if I asked a question it means that I'm not able to solve my problem so avoid links to other questions cause I've already read them

Comment: How do you install them?

Comment: I downloaded python from here https://www.python.org/downloads/
selenium as it says here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html with `pip install selenium` and `pip install instapy`

Comment: did you install pip separately?

Comment: not sure about what you mean but I guess so cause python and pip where already installed

Comment: can you check if you can execute `pip3` command?

Comment: pip3 -V
pip 21.0.1 from d:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Comment: Try to install the same packages using `pip3`, not `pip`

Comment: Damn "Requirement already satisfied"